# PDF-LIB SingleLineTextLayout example

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I am needing to right align some text in a PDF I am creating with PDF-LIB, and I see in the API docs there is a function

SingleLineTextLayout with left, right, and center for alignment options

https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/singlelinetextlayout

https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/layoutsinglelinetextoptions

However, I have searched here and on Google and Bing and have not found any examples of how to use this function.  The API documentation for PDF-LIB does not include any code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer helped. 2 lines need correcting, though:

```
let centerText = setTextCenter(pages[0], font, fontSize)

let rightText = setTextRight(pages[0], font, fontSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `widthOfTextAtSize` font property like this:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(file) 
const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
const font = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.TimesRoman)
const fontSize = 10

let centerText = setPageTextCenter(pages[0], font, fontSize)

centerText('This text is center aligned', xPos, yPos)

let rightText = setPageTextCenter(pages[0], font, fontSize)

rightText('this text is right aligned', xPos, yPos)

const setTextCenter = (page, font, size) => {
    return (text, x, y) => {
        const widthText = font.widthOfTextAtSize(text, size)
        const props = {
            x: x - widthText / 2,
            y: y,
            size,
            font,
       }
       page.drawText(text, props)
    }
}

const setTextRight = (page, font, size) => {
    return (text, x, y) => {
        const widthText = font.widthOfTextAtSize(text, size)
        const props = {
            x: x - widthText,
            y: y,
            size,
            font,
       }
       page.drawText(text, props)
    }
}
```